# Are all partial sums based analyses of infinite summations consistent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it true that for an arbitrary infinite summation S, any analysis based on its partial sums will either diverge or return some constant k(S)?

Perhaps the analyses need some constraint; say that they have to be consistent with the limit of the partial sums of an arbitrary series, if both methods return a finite value.

In the case that the constraint is still ambiguous (or perhaps too restrictive); is it true that specifically Borel-, Cesàro-, Abel-, Ramanujan- and Euler summations are consistent for any series?

Comment: See this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/a/22889/454

Comment: Ah, thank you GEdgar.

I have a follow up question as well. How strong of a correlation can be found between partial sums analyses and analytic continuations? E.g, I know that 1-1+1-1+... has an analytic continuation that indeed assigns 1/2 to the series.

So, is this a coincidence or is there a group of partial sums based methods that are also consistent with analytic continuations?

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn some complex analysis before you investigate analytic continuation.

Comment: Given s(x) = 1+x+x^2+... = 1/(1-x) for |x|<1; 1/(1-x) is an analytic continuation of s(x) for all x$\neq$1. s(-1) = 1-1+1-1+... = 1/2. Are there continuations of other functions that can be used to represent 1-1+1-... that will give a different value to it? If not; then again, is it a coincidence that we get 1/2 or is a correlation with methods based on partial sums viable? If I am still not asking the correct questions, please try to explain why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G. H. Hardy, DIVERGENT SERIES, page 73:

> There is no general theorem for Abelian methods corresponding to Theorem 17: different methods may well sum the same series to different sums. Thus $1−1+1−\dots$ is summable (A) to sum $1/2$, but summable $(A,λ)$, where $(λ_n)$ is the sequence $0,1,3,4,6,7,\dots$, to $1/3$: see § 3.9.

The two methods Hardy mentions may both be considered "analytic continuation" methods.

**method $(A)$**

Consider
$$
s(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}x^k.
$$
Then for $|x| < 1$ we have
$$
s(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}.
$$
So this rational function is the analytic continuation of $s(x)$ to all complex numbers except $x= -1$. 
Let $x=1$ to get formally the series $1-1+1-1+\dots$ and the value $s(1) = 1/2$.

**method $(A,\lambda)$**

Take $(\lambda_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to be the sequence $(1,2,4,5,7,8,\dots)$, where the multiples of $3$ are omitted.  Consider
$$
v(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} x^{\lambda_n} = x-x^2+x^4-x^5+x^7-x^8+\cdots .
$$
Then for $|x|<1$ we have
$$
v(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} .
$$
So this rational function is the analytic continuation of $v(x)$.  Let $x=1$ to get formally the series $1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$ and the value $v(1) = 1/3$.

**summary:**

We may think the $s(x)$ method is "more natural" than the $v(x)$ method, but it is not because one is analytic continuation and the other isn't (since both are analytic continuation).

Comment: Oh. This has brought me both clarity and further pondering (I'll turn to Hardys book before posting here again though). Thank you kindly for taking your time with this.